# Windows 8 PDF Reader: does it support 3D viewing?

Tags: windows-8, pdf-reader

The PDF spec has several rather obscure features that aren't usually supported in readers other than Adobe's.  One of them is the ability to display 3D models that the user can rotate, zoom in, and zoom out to view.  Does anybody know if the built-in Windows 8 PDF reader supports that?

Comment: Did you try to view one of these PDFs in the Windows 8 Reader?  What happened when you did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not: `Windows 8 is shipped with a PDF reader that is not suitable for 3D PDF files`.
You can download such [Sample 3D PDF from this site](http://www.document3d.com/demos/pdf.htm) an try it yourself.

There is a free Windows 8 PDF viewer alternative to the Adobe Reader that is able to open 3D PD. [Soda PDF 3D Reader](http://sodapdf.com/products/free-pdf-reader) or directly in the Windows Store [Soda PDF 3D Reader](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/soda-pdf-3d-reader/2343f528-db01-4340-82bb-4fb6933df56c).

Comment: I was not able to open any of our documents in the Soda. I tried many PDFs from http://www.pdf3d.com/gallery.php. It seems Soda is 3D because of "cool" 3D pagination.